# How can I make a lazy/busy person respond to my email?

Tags: communication, united-kingdom, email, motivation

Imagine I sent an email with a question to a person working in the UK in an organisation with relaxed work standards. Technically it is his responsibility to reply but in reality I cannot complain to his manager, all I can do is to try to make him feel guilty for ignoring me. And the email is nor answered after few days.

What would be a template for a first reminder?

And if the email is still not answered for another few days what would be a second reminder?

And similarly a third one?

Comment: Do you also reside on the UK?

Comment: Also, why is this person's responsibility to reply? Are you two working together in some project? Is there a manager or person you two report to?

Answer (score 2):

If the other person is not responding to repeated emails my next step would be to pick up the phone and call them.  Your priority might not be their priority.

> Hi, did you get my request about ...?  Do you have time to talk now or when are you available to talk?

I started my working career before email was widely used (mail in Unix does not count).  Today we depend too much on impersonal communications (email & chat).  I fall into this trap.

Call them.

Comment: That is why I asked if OP also lives in the UK... because if he does *not*, then calling this person may not be viable. I also prefer a call rather than slower communication like chatting.

Comment: Agreed.  Time zone differences can make this difficult.  Still should be able to find a time when both are available.

Comment: @DarkCygnus , I still call my colleges in India who are more than a 12 hour time differential from me when the occasion warrants, You may have to think think about when to call farther in advance.

Comment: @HLGEM I am sure your colleagues over there do care about your priorities and won't hesitate in answering :)